# D3 selection and entry

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I'm trying to create elements using d3.js by first selecting a  tag using a unique identifier, in this case "mydat". However, the following code doesn't give me anything.

```
<body>
<div id="mydat"></div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script>
for (i=0; i<5; i++) {
d3.select("body").select("#mydat")
    .data(i.toString())
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .text(String)
}
</script>
</body>
```

On the other hand, if I use the selection using:

```
d3.select("body").select("div")
```

and remove the first

```
<div id="mydat"></div>
```

then I get

```
<div>1</div><div>2</div>
```

etc. I am puzzled. Why doesn't the first method of selecting, i.e.

```
d3.select("body").select("#mydat")
```

identify the existing 'div' tag and put the child 'div' tags inside? Also, why does the second method of selecting not work if I do not remove the existing 'div id="mydat"'? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do what you want is

```
var data = d3.range(0,5);

d3.select("body").select("#mydat")
    .selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("div")
    .text(function(d) { return d; })
```

The behavior you're encountering is a mix of two mistakes coming together in your code.

The first issue is that `.data()` is supposed to accept an array of data, and a string can be treated as an array of characters, so d3 breaks the strings apart into characters. For `0 <= i < 5`, this isn't obvious, but if you change `i` to go into double digits, you'll see `divs` that look like this:

```
<div>1</div> //10
<div>0</div>
<div>1</div> //11
<div>1</div>
<div>1</div> //12
<div>2</div>
```

The fix is to remove the loop, and pass in an array of data instead. Loops are a rarity in d3, since it has so many powerful features to operate on groups of elements at once.

The second issue, and the reason your selections aren't working as expected, has to do with parent elements.

> The implementation of enter.select is then specialized such that nodes
>   are inserted into the group’s parent, replacing the placeholder. This
>   is why it is critical to call selection.selectAll prior to a data
>   join: it establishes the parent node for entering elements.

[Source: Mike Bostock's explanation of selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/)

Basically, `append` will insert the elements into the element that's the parent node for the current selection. Since the current selection has never had a parent set with `selectAll`, you're running into weird behavior with parent nodes. Always set the parent node explicitly with a `selectAll`.

Comment: This is tricky stuff. So it seems the only purpose of calling selectAll('div') at this point is to get the parent node so that append('div') knows where to put it. Is this correct? I tried with selectAll('foo') and it doesn't seem to make any difference what I put as an argument.

Comment: Pretty much. What you put in matters if you're working with existing elements. The elements selected with `selectAll` are used to see how your new data matches up with old data. Since your data is all new, the comparison to the old data is unimportant, and so is your selection.

Comment: Just so that I understand the data() function, I replaced it with data(data, function(d) {return d;}). This gives me the same result, as expected. What happens if I have an array like data=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]] and want to display 1, 3, 5. I tried function(d){return d[0];} but this gives me 1,2  3,4  5,6. function(d,i){return d[i,0];} doesn't work either. What's the correct way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: To be sure I also tried function(d,i){return d[i][0];}, which gives nothing.

Comment: Ah, the second argument of `data()` is the key function, not the data to be used. Remember how I said it matches new data with old data? Well, it needs some way to know which data matches. It matches them based on what's in the key function. Since your first key function returned unique keys, there was no issue. Your second function doesn't give an actual key, so that's an issue. I think what you wanted to do was put that function in the `text()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a loop with d3, in this case.

Try:

```
var data = d3.range(0,5);
var sel = d3.select("#mydat").selectAll("div.mydatItem").data(data);
sel.enter().append("div").attr("class", "mydatItem");
sel.text(function(d) { return d;};
```

This will create:

```
<div id="mydat">
    <div class="mydatItem">0</div>
    <div class="mydatItem">1</div>
    <div class="mydatItem">2</div>
    <div class="mydatItem">3</div>
    <div class="mydatItem">4</div>
</div>
```

`select` only selects a single element, whereas `selectall` will select all the matching elements. That is, `select("div")` will select the first div it finds, and `selectAll("div")` will select every div.

I'm not entirely clear why you're getting the output you see, but your "`.data()`" call should pass an array of data. You normally pass a non-array item as "`data([item])`".

Answer (score -2):

Try this instead:

```
d3.select('#mydat')
```

instead of this

```
   d3.select('body').select('#mydat')
```

Comment: This makes no difference. The two statements are effectively the same.